# Google Spreadsheet Parsing Error Trying To Divide With AND

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

`=IF(AND(I2>0,H2>0), round(H2/I2), "")` This is the function I am trying to use.

I want the function to either stay blank if no data was put in from either H2 or I2, or show me the divided calculation (H2 value divided by I2 value). I copied this function from another spreadsheet document. It says "Parsing Error In Formula". **Please check the images below and ignore the "RPS WT" column.**

Sorry I am very new to Google Spreadsheets and I only need this one function to work.

["Parsing Error In Formula"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtNJq.png)

[Function shown inside cell here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yieZA.png)

Tried to dumb it down to `round(H2/I2)` but I want the IF function to work so it doesn't show a DIV/0 error when no data is put in either H2 or I2.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(H2<>"",I2<>""),ROUND(H2/I2),"")
```

The divide function is only run if H2 and I2 are not blank.

Comment: Still gives me an error, I don't know why.

Comment: Can you share the Spreadsheet or a sample that looks similar?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your formula and it is working well on my end. I think from your sample it is reading the H2 as a string instead of a number. Try formatting it to a number. From the Menu click **Format ->  Number -> `Number` or `Plain Text`** if you want to keep the currency symbol.

[image]

---

Your current formula works without an error:
[image]

Unless one of the cell is 0, this will return an error:
[image]

---

### Try:

Try this formula instead:

```
=IFERROR(round(H2/I2), "")
```

[image]

Comment: The other posted answer should work as well. If you are still having errors please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet so we are able to replicate what you have. Remove sensitive data if any. @dUtchhii_